# Does a mobile VPN provide anonymity when using apps?

Tags: vpn, mobile, anonymity

When employing a system-wide VPN on a smartphone, I understand that all web traffic is routed through that VPN. Browsing to a webpage in incognito mode would provide some degree of anonymity, but I'm wondering to what extent installed apps can be trusted.

I'm assuming any app can retrieve and store unique device information such as UUID's, advertising ID's and such. When using an app both with and without a VPN enabled on different occasions, am I right in saying that this app can potentially link web traffic such as API requests and in-app WebView requests to the same device in both cases? If so, using a mobile VPN would not guarantee any privacy or anonymity. My question would then be: is there any way of 'sandboxing' an app so that usage of this app cannot be linked to previous usage of the same app?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb VPNs don't offer any anonymity.  They simply mask the source computer of a request.  If you publish on Facebook through a VPN, everyone will still know that you are doing the publishing because it is on your Facebook page.  Similarly, if you browse the internet and then turn on the VPN, websites will still track you with cookies they had installed (as well as other similar methods).

Comment: There seems to be a common misunderstanding of Privacy or Incognito mode. It does **not** provide anonymity! It simply makes sure that there are no data/cookie remnants from one browsing session to another, i.e. after shutdown and restart. Within a session it's a plain browser, there is no special protection.

Comment: @Conor Mancone - Perhaps it's symantics but I would say that VPNs do **offer** anonymity. It's just that if you insist on identifying yourself anyway you still can.

Comment: @user10216038 I'm happy to argue semantics, and I don't entirely disagree with your statement.  However, VPNs are easily misunderstood, and it's not so simple as turning on a VPN and becoming magically anonymous (which I describe in a mildly antagonistic way because that is how it is often advertised by VPNs).  There are still many, many ways that you can be tracked across the web while using a VPN, and your average user won't know how to keep themselves anonymous, even while using a VPN.